# Solution to the poor free-text search of OpenStreetMap

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, openstreetmap, street-address

I've done a web site for my city (Québec) using all the side-roads pannels to give a fast look at where it is or isn't possible to park (accross the road).

The only problem is that we need to enter a very specific address format for it to find the place.

Example, "123 rue st jean" works, 
 but not "Subway", "Cineplex-odeon" or almost any other market/restaurent's name.

One solution would be to change our map from OSM (OpenStreetMap) to Google-map but it would be :

1- a long job (since I don't know how to do it)

2- not FREE (and since we haven't any way of making money out of the site yet it would be annoying)

The web site is [parkmoi.com](http://www.parkmoi.com) and use 123 rue st jean if you want to try it.

So... does anyone have either a way to improve address researches OR an explanation to change to Google-Map?

Comment: Up? this is do-able here? ^^'

Comment: I've switched to Google maps last week and noticed a lot of improvements on my web site. So i totally recommand it. I'll post a full answer later when I have time for it.